# How do I declaritively set the dafault value on a RadioGroup

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I want to declare a default value in my radio group.

Looking at the API it seems I should use **'value'**, and point the value of value to an **'inputValue'**, like below :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.TestView', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    layout: 'form',

    items: [{
        name: 'tsk.forCase.estate.forcedSale',
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        fieldLabel: 'Group',

        value: 1,

        items: [{
            boxLabel: 'Item 1',
            name: 'rb',
            inputValue: 1
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Item 2',
            name: 'rb',
            inputValue: 2
        }]
    }, 
    ]
});
```

However, this does not work. Any ideas?

fiddle :

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1d8g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a radio group can contain multiple radio buttons *with different names*, the value is an object of the form `{radioFieldName: radioFieldInputValue, radioFieldName2: radioField2InputValue}`.

In your case, this is

```
value:{rb:1},
```